# Hide a table if all cells in tbody are empty

Tags: jquery

I would like to be able to hide an entire table if all the cells in tbody are empty. I have only been able to find out how to hide a single row, if all the cells in it were empty.

Here's the code. It is a dynamically generated table that I would like to hide it if it has no content in the body:

```
<table class="acf-dynamic-table ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Headline 1</th>
            <th>Headline 2</th>
            <th>Headline 3</th>
            <th>Headline 4</th>
            <th>Headline 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you very much for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($.trim($('.acf-dynamic-table tbody').text())=="") {
    $('.acf-dynamic-table').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".acf-dynamic-table td:not(:empty)").length == 0) {
  $(".acf-dynamic-table").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQUery [:empty selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) which:

> Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes)

```
 if ($(".acf-dynamic-table td:not(:empty)").length == 0) {
      $(".acf-dynamic-table").hide();
 }
```